# How to export data from Python database to Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, peewee

I am building WebApp with Pyhton Flask and peewee. I need to export data from the database and import it to Excel.

I found the **openpyxl** is python library for working with\n Excel spreadsheets.
This is my code:

models.py

```
class Info(Model):
    ime_prezime=CharField()
    ulica=CharField()
    broj=CharField()

    class Meta():
        database=DATABASE
```

```
import openpyxl
import models


wb=openpyxl.load_workbook("ispratnica.xlsx")
type(wb)
sheet = wb["Ispratnica"]
sheet["J2"].value="swongnwrb"
wb.save('{}.xlsx'.format(models.Info.ime_prezime))
```

When i change `wb.save('{}.xlsx'.format(models.Info.ime_prezime))` to ```wb.save('ispratnica1.xlsx'.) the code works perfectly, but when I try use data from the database it gives me error:

`OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '<CharField: Info.ime_prezime>.xlsx'`
Can someone help me with this one? Please pardon me if I have any mistakes asking this question.

Comment: it's just a filename issue then. `models.Info.ime_prezime` is not returning a proper string. `models.Info.ime_prezime` is a column from the look of it. Are you trying to use the name of the model?

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy I want to use the data stored into the ```models.Info.ime_prezime```column  and save the file with that name.

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#saving-to-a-file. You want to save the data to excel but `wb.save('{}.xlsx'.format(models.Info.ime_prezime))` is asking `openpyxl` to save an excel file named `'<CharField: Info.ime_prezime>.xlsx'`. That won't work. You need to read the data and write it to the workbook and save it

Comment: @NenadRistov: Use `filename = str(models.Info.ime_prezime).split()[1][:-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the data out and write it to a csv.

You need to actually *query* your model in order to have anything to write out.

```
import csv

with open('sheet.csv', 'w') as fh:
    writer = csv.writer(fh)
    for row in Info.select().tuples():
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: You do the same to Excel with openpyxl.